# Cut off string at not allowed tags in regex

Tags: php, regex

I got this fine working regex to use with php's preg_match_all to match a string containing 0 to x lines before and 0 to y lines after a specific word in a sentence/string:

```
'(?:[^\.?!<]*[\.?!]+){0,x}(?:[^\.?!]*)'.$word.'(?:[^\.?!]*)(?:[\.?!]+[^\.?!]*){0,y}'.'(?:[\.?!]+)'
```

Now, I want the string to be cut off when specific tags occur. So I was thinking about implementing this part in this string above:

```
(?:(<\/?(?!'.$allowed_tags.')))
```

in which $allowed_tags is a php variable that could look like this for example: `'(frame|head|span|script)'`

Despite trying to get this to work with lookahead, lookbehind and other conditions I can't get it working properly and I unfortunately have to admit this is way beyond my programming skills.

Hopefully someone can help me with this? I am sure someone among you geniuses can :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Example input-output:

For example I would like to grab this part:

```
<p>Tradition, Expansion, Exile.<br/>Individual paths in Chinese contemporary art </p><p>The contemporary <i>art world</i> craves for novelty: the best reason for Chinese art to be so trendy is also the <strong>worst one</strong>.</p>
```

from this complete string:

```
<div readability="120"><p>Tradition, Expansion, Exile.<br/>Individual paths in Chinese contemporary art </p><p>The contemporary <i>art world</i> craves for novelty: the best reason for Chinese art to be so trendy is also the <strong>worst one</strong>.</p><div>
```

That means in this example `<p></p><i></i><strong></strong> <br/>` are allowed tags and `<div    >` and `</div>` aren't.

Comment: Post some example input and output.

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for taking a look at this problem. I added a random input-output example. Hope you can help me!

Comment: If you want to parse HTML in PHP, I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php may be useful. There's a discussion on why trying to parse HTML with regexes is not such a good idea at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The off-topic answer would be to use e.g. QueryPath and select the desired content with `qp($html)->find("div p")->html();`. Not sure about your length or other matching exceptions, too vague. -- Matching with a regex is certainly doable, but heaps more effort. So if you aren't well-versed, try another approach.

Comment: Parsing the small pieces of (html) content I want to with this regex is working fine up till now. As I wrote in the question the first piece of code is working just fine. The only problem is I can't figure out how to cut off the output string at tags I don't want to allow. So, without meaning to be ungratefull for your comment, I think the discussion is not about wether or not to use regex for parsing this content, but about a last bit of finetuning to a already working code, so it doesn't look for more full sentences if it comes along a tag before or in a sentence that I don't want to allow.

Comment: @Emiel I wouldn't use regular expressions. Take Andrew Morton's suggestion.

Comment: I don’t think this is so much an issue of *parsing* HTML with a regex (which I agree is a bad idea) as of *matching* HTML, which regexes are perfectly adequate for. However, I am not sure I understand the intent correctly: Do you want to filter out the “illegal” tags from the string, with or without their content (`<b>a <span>b</span> c</b>` => `<b>a b c</b>` or => `<b>a  c</b>`)? to match strings only inside  “illegal” tags (`<b>a <span>b</span> c</b>` =>  `b`)? to match strings inside “legal” tags and cut those off at “illegal” tags (<b>a <span>b</span> c</b>` => `<b>a ` or => `<b>a</b>`)?

Comment: @kopischke: Thanks for your comment! You are perfectly right, this is an issue of matching a textfeed which sometimes contains html tags, so I too think regex is adequate for this job. The first piece of code works fine, it matches 0 to x sentences before and 0 to y sentences after a specific word ($word) in a string. The intent is to do the same (match 0 to x sentences before and 0 to y sentences after a specific word ($word) ), but now **inside** illegal tags (so the string gets cut off if an "illegal" tag occurs before the maximum number (x oor y) of full sentences is reached).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you define `div` and `span` tags as “illegal” [as per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064322/cut-off-string-at-not-allowed-tags-in-regex#comment14490912_11064322), the following regex will match `x` sentences before and `y` sentences after the sentence conatining `$word`, as long as those sentences do not contain the “illegal” tags:

```
'(?:(?<=[.!?]|^)(?:(?<!<div|<\/div|<span|<\/span)>|[^>.!?])+[.!?]+){0,x}[^.!?]*'.$word.'[^.!?]*[.!?]+(?:(?:<(?!\/?div|\/?span)|[^<.!?])*[.!?]+){0,y}'
```

Split up and explained (quotes and string concatenation operator removed, comments and line breaks added for better reading):

```
                                     // 0 TO X LEADING SENTENCES
(?: ---------------------------------// do not create a capture group
  (?<=[.!?]|^) ----------------------// match only after sentence end or start of string
  (?: -------------------------------// do not create a capture group
    (?<!<div|<\/div|<span|<\/span)> -// match “>” only if not preceded by span or div tags
    |[^>.!?] ------------------------// or any any other, non punctuation character
  )+ --------------------------------// one or more times
  [.!?]+ ----------------------------// followed by one or more punctuation characters
){0,x} ------------------------------// the whole sentence repeated 0 to x times
                                     // MIDDLE SENTENCE WITH KEYWORD
[^.!?]* -----------------------------// match 0 or more non-punctuation characters
$word -------------------------------// match string value of $word
[^.!?]* -----------------------------// match 0 or more non-punctuation characters
[.!?]+ ------------------------------// followed by one or more punctuation characters
                                     // 0 TO Y TRAILING SENTENCES
(?: ---------------------------------// do not create a capture group
  <(?!<\/?div|\/?span) --------------// match “<” not followed by a “div” or “span” tag
  |[^<.!?] --------------------------// or any non-punctuation character that is not “<”
  )* --------------------------------// zero or more times
  [.!?]+ ----------------------------// followed by one or more punctuation characters
){0,y} ------------------------------// the whole sentence repeated 0 to y times
```

Note the lookbehind assertion used for matching sentences before `$word` will only match opening and closing tags without attributes, and has to match both the opening and closing tag variants literally, [as lookbehind assertions cannot be of variable length](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.assertions.php). There are other limitations and gotchas:

- notably that the regex will return an “illegal” tag if it is located *inside* the sentence containing `$word`
- and that “inside” a sentence literally means “following the closing punctuation of the preceding sentence”, which, although formally correct, might not be what is expected.

**All of this goes to highlight the limitations of a regex based approach to the problem.** In this light, you might think that switching to a more programatic approach (like parsing all sentences into an array irrespective of tags, then scanning for “illegal” tags and trimming or rejecting the array accordingly, which would allow for a more flexible tag matching regex) would work better, and you would be right, were it not for the underlying difficulty of matching a natural language construct like a sentence with a regex with any degree of accuracy. I’ll leave you to ponder what the “sentence splitting” regex used in this question and answer would do to the following:

> “T.J. Hooker was plaid (sic.) by W. Shatner of Starship Enterprise (!) fame”

It’s not pretty. And neither is the result.

Comment: Thanks for your very complete answer kopischke! I was already reconsidering and will reconsider a programatic way to cut off the textfeed at illegal tags before using the "sentence regex". I think that way it will work even faster too, don't you think? Thanks for your effort again, especially for the explained piece of regex code, very cool! Thanks.